# Properties aren't ordered alphabetically

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I noticed that the ORDER BY clause orders text according to ASCII order, not alphabetically, like, for example, MySQL does.

In other words, this is how Neo4J would order properties:

```
Apple  
Carrot  
banana
```

And MySQL would order them like this:

```
Apple  
banana  
Carrot
```

What is the best way to get Neo4J to sort alphabetically? One way is to use upper (or lower) like this:

`MATCH (e) RETURN e.name ORDER BY upper(e.name) ASC;`

Another idea is to create a new property, nameSort, which is the same as the name property, but in upper (or lower) case.

Any other ways to do it? I would prefer to do something simple, like the Cypher modification above, rather than creating a new property, but I don't know what the performance implications are.

Comment: If the returned data size is small, it is easier to use a modifier in the query. If not, then, in my opinion, it is better to add a new property, where the value is stored in uppercase (or lowercase) and be sure to create index on this property.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j performs lexicographic string ordering, which is what you're seeing. This is documented [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-ordering). To achieve case-insensitive ordering, you'd need to implement this on your own (such as your suggestion for converting the case either during the query or when storing the property value).

Comment: Specifically, the lexicographic ordering of _Unicode._ (Case sensitivity aside, it may or may not have some language's alphabet in order; It depends on the language and the writing system.)